# access linksys router admin module remotely if linksys is behind a linux router

Tags: linux, firewall, ubuntu, iptables

My linksys wireless router is behind a Linux router and I would like to access the linksys router's admin module remotely.

How do I configure iptables so I can open the admin module?

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i $EXT_IF --dport $PORT -j DNAT --to-destination $IP
```

Am i missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd highly recommend not exposing your linksys administrative interface to the Internet. If you want to admin remotely tunnel through over SSH (at the very least) or a IPSEC VPN.

Comment: @ceretullis - but is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible via port forwarding (PAT) or static NAT... probably you want to search for port forwarding with iptables.

Comment: BTW, the linksys wireless router firmware has to be configured to listen on the WAN interface also ;) You can't do that from your iptables config, you need to modify the wireless router config too.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that you don't try to access the admin services directly from outside: you'll spend time trying some exotic forwarding to get it right and it likely won't be very secure.  For my purposes, I usually ssh into a machine inside the router's network and use lynx from there to connect back into the router's admin services.  The character interface is a bit rustic, but it works for me.  It probably won't work for admin services that want to do fancy-schmancy javascript-based whizzies.

(added later:) For a little fancier work, you can use `ssh -X` to get Xwindow traffic forwarded to your desktop - this allows you to start your favorite graphical browser (e.g. Firefox) on the target machine to see the admin screens of the router.

Comment: I do the same but use ssh tunneling so I can use a graphical browser. You simply tell your ssh client to create a tunnel over the ssh connection, that connects port 1234 on local to linksys:80 on remote (substitute the correct name or ip). Then you point your browser to http://localhost:1234/ and there is your linksys GUI. See http://www.ssh.com/support/documentation/online/ssh/adminguide/32/Port_Forwarding.html for more details. I use Putty to do this, so you don't need the CLI client.

Comment: Yep - that works, too.